# How to use characters in variables summing in R?

Tags: r

I have some dataframe. Here is a small expample:

```
a <- rnorm(100, 5, 2)
b <- rnorm(100, 10, 3)
c <- rnorm(100, 15, 4)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)
```

And I have a character variable `vect <- "c('a','b')"`

When I try to calculate sum of vars using command

```
df$d <- df[vect]
```

which must be an equivalent of

```
df$d <- df[c('a','b')]
```

But, as a reslut I have got an error

```
[.data.frame(df, vect) :undefined columns selected
```

Comment: Try `vect <- c('a','b')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assumption that

```
vect <- "c('a','b')"
df$d <- df[vect]
```

is equivalent to

```
df$d <- df[c('a','b')]
```

is incorrect.

As @Karthik points out, you should remove the quotation marks in the assignment to `vect`

However, from your question it sounds like you want to then sum the elements specified in `vect` and then assign to `d`. To do this you need to slightly change your code

```
vect <- c('a','b')
df$d <- apply(X = df[vect], MARGIN = 1, FUN = sum)
```

This does elementwise `sum` on the columns in `df` specified by `vect`. The `MARGIN = 1` specifies that we want to apply the sum rowise rather than columnwise.

**EDIT:**
As @ThomasIsCoding points out below, if for some reason `vect` has to be a string, you can parse a string to an R expression using `str2lang`

```
vect <- "c('a','b')"
parsed_vect <-  eval(str2lang(vect))
df$d <- apply(X = df[parsed_vect], MARGIN = 1, FUN = sum)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what exactly I want.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can try

```
> df[eval(str2lang(vect))] 
             a          b
1    8.1588519  9.0617818
2    3.9361214 13.2752377
3    5.5370983  8.8739725
4    8.4542050  8.5704234
5    3.9044461 13.2642793
6    5.6679639 12.9529061
7    4.0183808  6.4746806
8    3.6415608 11.0308990
9    4.5237453  7.3255129
10   6.9379168  9.4594150
11   5.1557935 11.6776181
12   2.3829337  3.5170335
13   4.3556430  7.9706624
14   7.3274615  8.1852829
15  -0.5650641  2.8109197
16   7.1742283  6.8161200
17   3.3412044 11.6298940
18   2.5388981 10.1289533
19   3.8845686 14.1517643
20   2.4431608  6.8374837
21   4.8731053 12.7258259
22   6.9534912  6.5069513
23   4.4394807 14.5320225
24   2.0427553 12.1786148
25   7.1563978 11.9671603
26   2.4231207  6.1801862
27   6.5830372  0.9814878
28   2.5443326  9.8774632
29   1.1260322  9.4804636
30   4.0078436 12.9909014
31   9.3599808 12.2178596
32   3.5362245  8.6758910
33   4.6462337  8.6647953
34   2.0698037  7.2750532
35   7.0727970  8.9386798
36   4.8465248  8.0565347
37   5.6084462  7.5676308
38   6.7617479  9.5357666
39   5.2138482 13.6822924
40   3.6259103 13.8659939
41   5.8586547  6.5087016
42   4.3490281  9.5367522
43   7.5130701  8.1699117
44   3.7933813  9.3241308
45   4.9466813  9.4432584
46  -0.3730035  6.4695187
47   2.0646458 10.6511916
48   4.6027309  4.9207746
49   5.9919348  7.1946723
50   6.0148330 13.4702419
51   5.5354452  9.0193366
52   5.2621651 12.8856488
53   6.8580210  6.3526151
54   8.0812166 14.4659778
55   3.6039030  5.9857886
56   9.8548553 15.9081336
57   3.3675037 14.7207681
58   3.9935336 14.3186175
59   3.4308085 10.6024579
60   3.9609624  6.6595521
61   4.2358603 10.6600581
62   5.1791856  9.3241118
63   4.6976289 13.2833055
64   5.1868906  7.1323826
65   3.1810915 12.8402472
66   6.0258287  9.3805249
67   5.3768112  6.3805096
68   5.7072092  7.1130150
69   6.5789349  8.0092541
70   5.3175820 17.3377234
71   9.7706112 10.8648956
72   5.2332127 12.3418373
73   4.7626124 13.8816910
74   3.9395911  6.5270785
75   6.4394724 10.6344965
76   2.6803695 10.4501753
77   3.5577834  8.2323369
78   5.8431140  7.7932460
79   2.8596818  8.9581837
80   2.7365174 10.2902512
81   4.7560973  6.4555758
82   4.6519084  8.9786777
83   4.9467471 11.2818536
84   5.6167284  5.2641380
85   9.4700525  2.9904731
86   4.7392906 11.3572521
87   3.1221908  6.3881556
88   5.6949432  7.4518023
89   5.1435241 10.8912283
90   2.1628966 10.5080671
91   3.6380837 15.0594135
92   5.3434709  7.4034042
93  -0.1298439  0.4832707
94   7.8759390  2.7411723
95   2.0898649  9.7687250
96   4.2131549  9.3175228
97   5.0648105 11.3943350
98   7.7225193 11.4180456
99   3.1018895 12.8890257
100  4.4166832 10.4901303
```